# Simplification of series (A good approximation will also work)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, exponential-function

I have solved a system of linear ODEs and obtained a solution of the form
$
y_{ij}(t)=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma^{i(i-1)}}{\gamma^{j(j-1)}}}(\frac{-2\epsilon}{\alpha})^{i-j} \sum_{h=j}^i\frac{e^{-\frac{\alpha \gamma^h}{n_0}t}}{\prod_{l=j,l\neq h}^i(\gamma^h - \gamma^l)}, i \ge j
$

where $\gamma, n_0, \epsilon, \alpha $ are $+ive$ constants and $t$ is the time. I need this solution to be more simple, as I am interested to find a nice expression for $\frac{y_{i-1j}}{y_{ij}}$. I tried to use first-degree Taylor's polynomial (expansion about the origin), but that's not a good representation of the desired ratio of the original solution. Can we approximate the above solution, which gives a good representation?
The second part of my question is that if we plot $y_{ij}(t)$ for $i=3, j=1, \gamma=1.26, \epsilon=0.85, n_0=400, \alpha=2\epsilon-1$, we get an almost bell-shaped curve skewed on the right. That means that there is an increase to a certain peak and then a decrease continues. My question is, can we approximate the rate of increase of the curve?

Comment: $$\sum_{h=j}^i\frac{e^{-\frac{\alpha \gamma^h}{n_0}t}}{\prod_{l=j,l\neq h}^i(\gamma^h - \gamma^j)} = \sum_{h=j}^i\frac{e^{-\frac{\alpha \gamma^h}{n_0}t}}{(\gamma^h - \gamma^j)^{i-j}} = (\gamma^h - \gamma^j)^{j-i}\sum_{h=j}^ie^{-\frac{\alpha \gamma^h}{n_0}t}$$

Comment: @amsmath Thanks for your response. I am sorry there was a mistake in the denominator inside the summation. before it was $\prod_{l=j,l \ne h}^i(\gamma^h-\gamma^j)$, which is now corrected to $\prod_{l=j,l \ne h}^i(\gamma^h-\gamma^l)$.